# Specifying only width or height for an img element

Tags: html, html4

If only one of the attributes `height` or `width` is set for an `img` element, most browsers seem to keep the proportions of the image.

This is from the HTML 4.01 reference:

> When the object is an image, it is scaled. User agents should do their
>   best to scale an object or image to match the width and height
>   specified by the author.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG

Would it be wrong of a browser to scale the image non-uniformly, that is changing only the height or the width of an image?

Update 2015-08-12: [Dillo](http://www.dillo.org/) (version 3.0.4) is an example of a browser which does not keep the proportions of an image if only *height* or only *width* is set.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at what Bootstrap does with the .img-responsive class, it only sets height and max-width. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

If a browser didn't auto scale the width based on the height, this widely used CSS package would fail.

Comment: Yes, many images on the web are incorrectly displayed if the browser doesn't make sure that the scaling is uniform.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the spec authors, but from my PoV as a web developer if you scale non-uniformly your user agent is broken and none of my sites will render properly for you.  Why would I ever want a non-uniform scaling?  Especially one where one side is just determined by whatever size the image happens to be?

Comment: I agree, non-uniform scaling of photos is a big no-no.